# не получается отправлять данные формы через ajax в symfony

Tags: php, ajax, form, symfony

{% block javascripts %}

```
  <script language = "javascript"
        src = "../../../../../web/resources/js/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
   <script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mySubmitButton").on("click", function (event) {
            var val = $( ":input" ).serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://lessonsphp.loc/data.php",
                data: {user: 'aa'},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async:      true,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

```
 <div class="container">
     <!-- row -->
     <h2 class="m-2">Add User</h2>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="section-row">
             {{ form_start(form) }}
             {{ form_widget(form.username,{'attr': {'class': 'form- 
control','placeholder':'Username'}}) }}
             {{ form_widget(form.email,{'attr': {'class': 'form- 
control','placeholder':'Email'}}) }}
             {{ form_widget(form.password,{'attr': {'class': 'form- 
control','placeholder':'Password'}}) }}
             {{ form_widget(form.website,{'attr': {'class': 'form- 
control','placeholder':'Website'}}) }}
             {{ form_widget(form.fname,{'attr': {'class': 'form- 
control','placeholder':'First name'}}) }}
             {{ form_widget(form.lname,{'attr': {'class': 'form- 
 control','placeholder':'Last name'}}) }}
             <button type="button" id="mySubmitButton" class="btn btn- 
    default m-1"> Save</button>
             {{ form_end(form) }}
         </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /row -->
 </div>
```

{% endblock %}

//controller

```
public function addUserAction(Request $request){

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $resp = $_POST['userData'];
        return new JsonResponse($resp);
    }

    $addUser = new Users();
    $form = $this->createForm(addUser::class, $addUser);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $addUser->setCreatedDate(new \DateTime());

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($addUser);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_homepage');
    }
    return $this->render('@Blog/pages/addUser.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать строки contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async:      true, и попробовать снова

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в ajax запросе,

```
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{ path('addUser') }}',
                data: {'user': val},
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```